# Spring Docker container cannot access Postgres Docker container

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

The Dockerfile of my spring-boot app:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/media-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/media
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: 30000
```

and here is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: media
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Running `docker-compose up --build` results in:

> app_1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 0.0.0.0:5432
>   refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
>   postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. app_1

My guess is that the spring app tries to connect to postgres before postgres is ready, but I get the following log:

> db_1   | 2019-05-18 19:05:53.692 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is
>   ready to accept connections

Comment: I doubt that `0.0.0.0` would work (and `localhost` definitely won't work, since the database is not in the same container as your app). In Docker Compose, other services are made available via virtual DNS, so you should be able to use `db` instead.

Comment: So, try connecting via `jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/media`.

Comment: Changing the `spring.datasource.url` to `jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/media`, as you suggested, made it work. Thanks. Feel free to make your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main purpose of Docker Compose is to spin up a set of Docker containers, which will then function as independent entities. By default, all containers will have a virtual network connection to all others, though you can change that if you wish; you will get that feature, since you have not specified a custom configuration.

Each of the containers will get a virtual IP address inside the virtual network set up by Docker. Since these are dynamic, Docker Compose makes it easier for you by creating internal DNS entries corresponding to each service. So, you will have two containers, which can be addressed as `app` and `db` respectively, either from themselves or the other. If you have ping installed, you can ping these names too, either via `docker-compose exec`, or via a manually-created shell.

Thus, as we discovered in the comments, you can connect from `app` to `jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/media`, and it should work.