# Connect MySQL to Spring Boot : Communication failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker compose and want to attach mysql to my spring boot application.

My compose file looks

```
version: '3'

volumes:
   mysql_data:

services:
   ww-mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
         - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      ports:
         - 3306:3306
      environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
         MYSQL_DATABASE: ww
         MYSQL_USER: admin
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin

ww-app:
      build: .
      image: ww-app
      ports:
         - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
         - ww-mysql
      links:
         - ww-mysql
```

Application properties that connect to mysql

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ww?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

The error I am getting

```
 2019-06-05 04:58:16.411 ERROR 6 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
ww-app_1    | 
ww-app_1    | com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
ww-app_1    | 
ww-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I am confused. I have mysql server running on my ubuntu 18

Comment: Your compose file not complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Docker container cannot access Postgres Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202090/spring-docker-container-cannot-access-postgres-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see you put a driver class name there.
//-- for mysql 5
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

//--for mysql 8

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: This solution didn't work

Answer (score 0):

change the JDBC URL to

> jdbc:mysql://ww-mysql:3306/ww?useSSL=false

The reason why you are getting that error is because both are running in a different container, you cannot tell Spring service to look for MySql connection in it's container.